# how to display data from IEnumerable in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to create an asp.net web application  . I have a simple database with 3 tables: projects,bugs and testers. I'm trying to display all bugs which are recorded for a selected project.
The problem is that I don't know how to display data from  IEnumerable bug.

On the default page I have a grid and in that grid I display all data from table projects. And for that grid I set the event selectedIndexChanging and I wrote this code:

```
 protected void grdProiecte_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(grdProiecte.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text);
            Server.Transfer("BugProject.aspx?idproiect=" + id.ToString());
        }
```

On the BugProject.aspx I wrote this in order to display data from bugs table when bugs.projectID=projects.projectID

```
IEnumerable<Bug> bug =db.Bugs.Where(s => s.ProjectID == idproiect );
```

Sorry for writting in this way , but I'm new and I'm not allowed to post images yet.

Comment: Please post a simplified example of your code.  As it is now, it is a little hard to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please add essential parts of your code. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for asking a better received question.

Comment: try List<Bug> bugList = db.Bugs.Where(s => s.ProjectID == idproiect ).ToList(); -  IEnumerable is just a non-generic way of display collection.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works!